# How do I set a tag via cookie and filter content on the whole site based on that tag?

Tags: cookies, taxonomy-terms

I have a site which has different tags for different cities. Most of the content on the site is either for all cities or a set of specific cities. I am planning to have all the content pieces taggable via taxonomy references. Within my template I want a dropdown which sets the current city. What is the easiest way to only show correct content based on this drop down througout the site?

Answer (score 1):

you can build a view to show your content, then add a "filter" for the city term and "expose it" to your visitors. There is an option to remember the selection for each user.

Answer (score 0):

The way to i do this is using the panel module (unfortunately this module is not yet available for Drupal 7)

When you use panels you can create regions where you can put many views or blocks and in these views you can set taxonomies as a filter.